# React - functional component container

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-component

I would like to create a container component in my application. I don't know if this is possible or if it's a good idea at all. I would be so very comfortable.

```
From this:

export default function App(){
    return(
           <div className={styles.CardsContainer}>
                <CardPrice price={700}/>
                <CardPrice price={3000}/>
                <CardPrice price={5000}/>
          </div>
    )
}

I want to do it:

export default function App(){
    return(
           <CardsContainer>
                <CardPrice price={700}/>
                <CardPrice price={3000}/>
                <CardPrice price={5000}/>
          </CardsContainer>
    )
}


I do this in CardsContainer:

export default function CardsContainer(){
    return(
           <div className={styles.CardsContainer}>

           </div>
    )
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work) But I don't know how to wrap properly.
I don't want to put components with CardPrice in a CardContainer component. I want to wrap in App component

Comment: You need to use the children prop, heres an existing thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272947/how-to-pass-this-props-children-using-hooks-in-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass this.props.children using hooks in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272947/how-to-pass-this-props-children-using-hooks-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this, but you will need to take de props.chidlren inside the container.

```
export default function CardsContainer({children}){
    return(
        <div className={styles.CardsContainer}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

but I think will be better if u use the styled component to create de container

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the elements as children to the CardsContainer and in CardsContainer component you can access it using the children prop. For a better understanding, you could refer these docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment

```
export default function CardsContainer({children}){
return(
       <div className={styles.CardsContainer}>
         {children}
       </div>
)
```